# How do I create a list of objects in c ++ and use its methods?

Tags: c++

I created this class and I need to use a for (iterator) to enter the values, they will not necessarily be i, any other value, for that I need to use a list:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;
// 1ra clase base
class Person {
  int e;

 public:
  Person(int);
  void printDates();
};

Person::Person(int x) { e = x; }
void Person::printDates() { cout << e; }
int main() {
  list<Person> persons;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Person person(i);
    persons.push_front(person);
  }
  // for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  // {
  //     hombres[i].printDates();
  // }
}
```

I need to use personDates method, and any other method you can add, either in a list or in another.

Comment: `for( auto& person : persons) { // do something with person }` online example here: [https://ideone.com/8lEv0C](https://ideone.com/8lEv0C)

Comment: What do you mean by "enter the values"? What is "personDates method"? Do you mean `printDates()`? What's wrong with the for loop you are using?

Comment: Maybe you need a [for each loop](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03f9XaC_m5i4C0ZFCaAZ6tkau8_ow%3A1604521063320&source=hp&ei=ZwyjX8mlEdLk-gSLkKcQ&q=c%2B%2B+for+each+loop&oq=c%2B%2B+for+each+loop&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCAAQyQMyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6BAgjECc6CAgAELEDEIMBOggILhCxAxCDAToICC4QxwEQowI6BQgAELEDOgUIABCSAzoFCC4QsQM6CwguELEDEMcBEKMCOgIILjoICAAQsQMQyQM6BAgAEApQ2QJYuSpgjyxoAHAAeACAAWKIAc0PkgECMjaYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiJ9Yvg2unsAhVSsp4KHQvICQIQ4dUDCAk&uact=5)?

Comment: Thank you, write your answer and I will rate it in answers @drescherjm

Comment: I think the answer by @Martin York is good.

Comment: Why are you using `std::list` anyway? Use `std::vector` instead as it's superior in almost all ways. And you don't need `push_front`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that list does not provide an `index` into the container.

```
persons[i] // does not work for list (though it does work for vector).
```

So you need to use an iterator.
Older versions of C++ this is done like this:

```
for(auto loop = persons.begin(); loop != persons.end(); ++loop) {
    loop->printDates();
}
```

In modern versions of C++ this is simplified to:

```
for(auto& item: persons) {
    item.printDates();
}
```